# await & async when you don't care about errors

Tags: javascript, async-await

Let's take a simple example, `fs.stat`.  I can promisify `fs.stat` and write:

```
const stats = await stat(file, fs.constants.R_OK);
```

but if the file doesn't exist this throws.  Other than wrapping every await in a try/catch, is there a clean pattern or wrapping library that can be used here?  Something that perhaps ends up with `stats === undefined | null`?

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this?

```
function caughtAwait(func){
  try{
    return await func();
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
}
const stats = caughtAwait(()=>stat(file, fs.constants.R_OK));
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering writing a simple lib like this that would also handle arrays (`Promise.all`) and anything else I can come up with.  I'm mostly curious if anyone's done this already and thought through the various cases

Comment: I understand, although what you want seems too simple and straight forward for using external libs IMHO. There is also a real chance I'm mistaken here. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple wrapper:

```
async function leniently(promise) {
     try {
        return await promise
     } catch(err) {
        return null
     }
}
```

Used for any promise:

```
const result = await leniently(stat(file, fs.constants.R_OK))
```

Or `Promise.all(...)`:

```
const result = await leniently(Promise.all(...))
```